# SPARK: How to monitor the memory consumption on Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

Sorry for the basic question, but i couldn't figured it out by myself.

I was trying to figure out on Spark UI how much memory is available and used on each worker and the driver.

Is there any straight-forward and **simple** way to monitor this information?

My goal is to decide my persistence strategy, according to how much my data occupy on the workers and on the driver.

P.S. I am using standalone mode, on Spark 1.6.1

Comment: I'm using `visualvm` for standalone and `ganglia` in cluster mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in the Executors tab you will have the info that you need. If you have spark up you will find it in http://localhost:4040/executors/
Best!